# WCF Service PHP Client

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wcf, soap-client

I’m trying to invoke a WCF service (.NET) from PHP but receive **object(SoapFault)#2 (9) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(21) "Internal Server Error"**.

My PHP Code is:

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://classifications.moh.gov.ge/Classifications/Services/ClassificationsWcf.svc?wsdl',
    array('trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

try {
    $ret = $client->ICDO_GetByID(array('ID' => 'A560CE4E-083C-48DA-B176-82DA393A3AF6'));
    print_r($ret);
}catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I check this service is work by C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceReference.ClassificationsWcfClient Client =new ServiceReference.ClassificationsWcfClient();
          var r = Client.ICDO_GetByID(new Guid());
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand the problems.

```
var_dump($this->Client->__getFunctions());
var_dump($this->Client->__getTypes());

__getFunctions and __getTypes Works without problems
```

PHP supports WCF?

Comment: enable php errors in .ini file or add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your PHP files

Comment: I receive:
 object(SoapFault)#2 (9) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(21) "Internal Server Error"

Comment: have you checked server err logs?

Comment: My error log is clean